# How to restrict akka from only starting up on a single server?

Tags: playframework, akka

When you create background jobs in akka e.g. run this database query every hour
You probably only want this to run on a single server since it is a time based job.

If you have your play app running on multiple servers, what is a good strategy of making sure only 1 server actually has your akka actors running (even though all servers have the same code).

Answer (score 1):

If you restrict the code to running on a single server, you'd introduce a Single Point of Failure - what happens if that server crashes, or becomes disconnected somehow?

You'll probably want to set up your `ActorSystem`s to form an Akka Cluster, and put the code you want to run in a centrally coordinated fashion in a [Cluster Singleton](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/cluster-singleton.html). In this case, Akka will make sure there's always one and only one instance of your Singleton running in the cluster (if the node running it should crash, it'll be restarted on another node).

Comment: I see your point, but for a small'ish implementation that doesn't need that type of redundancy...